# Write an NFC application that preempts all other NFC applications

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

Is there a way to make an NFC application read a tag over all other applications that may be downloaded on the phone?

Usually, if more than one application can read a given tag, then the user is prompted with which application to open. I would like to skip this step and have my application automatically open.

Any resources or actual code would be really helpful. This is just part of a research project so I don't even need to code the application, I would just like to know if it is possible and potentially build a proof of concept application if I have time.

Comment: Did you check out the Android Application Record?

Comment: What did you try yourself already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can use filters to specify a specific NDEF tag type to look for. In that case only your app would be brought up, but if another app is also looking for that exact same tag type, both apps will be brought up.